# Slice last and last-2 rows for each group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, slice

Let;s say I have data set and would like to select in grouping 3rd and 5th rows:

```
   df <- data.table(
     x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
     d = c("2022-05-01", "2022-05-02", "2022-05-03", "2022-05-04", "2022-05-05"))
```

I need to select by using `slice()` and `row_number()` only "3" and "5" rows.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(d) %>% 
  arrange(d) %>%
  slice(tail(row_number()-2, row_number())) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Why not just `x[c(3,5)]`?

Comment: Why do you have to do `dplyr` operations on a `data.table`?

Comment: x[c(3,5), ] in fact  - this is simplified version - the real one is in a big %>% code

Comment: So what are you looking for? It's not clear

Comment: I updated code. I need to select Last and Last -2 rows only

Comment: In your example data we have 1 item per group, how do you want to get last row which is 1, and 2 rows before last row which is -1?

Answer (score 3):

Like this? It should work with `group_by()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  slice(n()-2, n())
```

Answer (score 3):

Using *data.table* with maybe a better example data, try this:

```
library(data.table)

# example data
x <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl %in% c(4, 6), c("cyl", "mpg")]
setDT(x)

# order by mpg and get Nth and Nth-2 rows per cyl
x[order(mpg), .SD[ { ind = (.N - c(2, 0)); ind[ind > 0]; }, ], by = cyl ]
#    cyl  mpg
# 1:   6 21.0
# 2:   6 21.4
# 3:   4 30.4
# 4:   4 33.9
```

Comment: For a defensive addition, consider grouped that are only 1-2 rows .. could do `.SD[if (.N > 2) .N-c(2,0) else .N,]`, not pretty but more resilient.

Comment: @r2evans good point, I didn’t consider cases with less than 3 cases. Feel free to edit.

Comment: The `if` in my previous comment works with this example but does not fair as well in the more general sense, perhaps where `- c(2, 0)` is extended to `c(4, 2, 0)` and one wants to retain as many of the candidate rows as possible. The version in my suggested edit is more robust to that, even if it looks a bit clunky. An alternative to _that_ can be `x[order(mpg), .SD[ seq(.N) %in% (.N-c(2,0)), ], by = cyl ]`, though with larger data, that's calling `seq` a lot, which in the end is not really necessary (even if it is not a lot of overhead).